# 'pipenv install -r' is not working

Tags: python, django, pip, cookiecutter, pipenv

Excuted this : 'pipenv install -r requirements/local.txt'

```
D:\doc\jaeeongram> pipenv install -r requirements/local.txt
Requirements file provided! Importing into Pipfile…
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
```

Nothing happens here. (After 5min, ...., 1hour)

The following is my Pipfile.

```
[[source]]

url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"


[packages]

Django = "==1.10.8"
django-environ = "==0.4.4"
django-crispy-forms = "==1.7.0"
django-model-utils = "==3.0.0"
Pillow = "==4.3.0"
"argon2_cffi" = "==16.3.0"
django-allauth = "==0.34.0"
awesome-slugify = "==1.6.5"
pytz = "==2017.3"
django-redis = "==4.8.0"
redis = ">=2.10.5"
coverage = "==4.4.2"
django_coverage_plugin = "==1.5.0"
Sphinx = "==1.6.5"
django-extensions = "==1.9.8"
Werkzeug = "==0.13"
django-test-plus = "==1.0.21"
factory_boy = "==2.9.2"
django-debug-toolbar = "==1.9.1"
ipdb = "==0.10.3"
pytest-django = "==3.1.2"
pytest-sugar = "==0.9.0"


[dev-packages]



[requires]

python_version = "3.6"
```

pipenv shell -> django-admin
not found...

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: django-admin is not in your file. what exactly the issue? can you elaborate what exactly happens and what it should be?

Comment: I want to install packages.

so I ran the following command to install the package into the virtual environment.

* command : pipenv install -r requirements/local.txt

But it does not work.

Comment: This is because the installation of some packages is infinitely delayed.